# How to sync forked repo with commits in the Pull Request on github?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a github repository, created another branch and after making my changes opened a Pull Request.

Then author of repo made his own changes and committed.

Normally, I thought that his commit/changes will get in sync with mine unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case when I checked locally.

How to get his commits to my forked repo?

**EDIT:**

after trying to fetch and rebase from upstream, I getting the following error:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'upstream/mybranchname'
```

The Pull Request on Github has fewer commits, author apparently squashed them.

The Pull Request is still open and it hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout your branch, then do:

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
git push -f
```

Then do the pull request again.

In the unlikely event that the remote for the repo owner is not called `upstream` or the branch you want to merge into is not called `master`, you will need to change those.

If you don't have an upstream remote, you need to add it with:

`git remote add upstream https://github.com/somename/somerepo.git`

where the last parameter points to the repo owner's repo.

Also there may be conflicts on the rebase.  Either resolve them or do:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Comment: @konekoya, yes because he already pushed his branch before rebasing

Comment: @JoelFan thank you for your reply! I getting an error while doing this. Could you please check edit

Comment: @MartinSergio, hey, would love to see which command it was and what the exact error message was ;)

Comment: @JoelFan I used exact commands provided by you, the Error message is on my question's Edit

Comment: @MartinSergio, Look in the part of my answer starting with "If you don't have an upstream remote..."